# Tide mode: how do I get it to stop running tide-format-before-save?

Tags: hooks, formatting, javascript

I'm at my utter wit's end with this hell-plugin lmao. I've tried `(remove-hook 'before-save-hook 'tide-format-before-save t)`, and it doesn't work. How do I remove `tide-format-before-save` from the `before-save-hook` so that Tide doesn't completely mutilate prettier-js's formatting every time I save? I'd really like to be able to commit files to the FOSS project I'm contributing to that aren't 90% one character formatting edits. I just need Tide to stop butting in and changing things so I can use the formatting program the project uses. Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure the `formatting` and `javascript` tags are relevant? Your question isn't very clear, but it sounds like it's just a question about removing a hook. You don't show any code or any recipe to repro the problem... Do you see the problem if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file) and you add the hook then try to remove it (or whatever the recipe is). If not, bisect your init file to find the culprit.

Comment: You need to find the place in your init file where you are adding the function to the hook and delete that line. You are probably trying to remove it before it has been added; so alternatively, you can try moving the `remov-hook` line to the *end* of your init file. That might work, but it's better to find the `add-hook` line and delete that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out all I had to do was remove the `t` argument at the end there and it worked